# MySQL - Join records where all sub records have a value

Tags: mysql, sql, join

**PART 1**

Let's say I have an **orders** table, and each order has one or more instalments.

**instalments**

```
id  |  order_id  |  customer_id  |  timestamp
-------------------------------------------------------
1   |      1     |       5       |  2014-10-31 00:00:00
2   |      1     |       5       |  NULL
3   |      1     |       5       |  2014-10-31 00:00:00
4   |      2     |       8       |  2014-10-31 00:00:00
5   |      2     |       8       |  2014-10-31 00:00:00
6   |      2     |       8       |  2014-10-31 00:00:00
7   |      3     |       5       |  2014-10-31 00:00:00
```

I want to retrieve all orders where all the instalments have a timestamp, and the largest of those timestamps is within the last X days.

In the above table, I should retrieve order ID 2 and 3, but not 1 because one of the instalments has a NULL timestamp.

What is the most efficient way I can do this? I don't really know where to start, but I think I need a subquery of some sort to work with the data later.

**PART 2**

Ultimately, what I am trying to do here is get a count of how many orders each customer has which pass the test in part 1 (only orders where all instalments have a timestamp), and I will compare that with another value.

So once I have a result set containing all the orders where all instalments have a timestamp, how can I also group those to include a count for each customer who qualifies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select order_id
from order
group by order_id
having sum(timestamp is null) = 0
```

for the second part of your question:

```
select customer_id, count(distinct order_id) as unique_orders
from order
where timestamp is not null
group by customer_id
```

Comment: Thanks, that was quick. I've added a second part to the question, which elaborates on where I'm going with this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT count(*), customer_id
FROM order
WHERE timestamp is not null
GROUP BY customer_id
```